# How to handle c library in multithreading

Tags: java, c, multithreading, operating-system

I have a main method which has two methods 
1) A Method which returns a handle to a library .
2) I use this handle in other method .

I call this main method from java thread using JNI . 
The problem is when multiple threads run from java callout(OSB) and call the main method  it opens the handle to library multiple times . 
I want to open this handle  only once for multiple thread (i.e call method one only once for both the threads).
I cannot do this on java side (Due to some constraints) . 
Is there any way to this from C program i tried using IPC but the address returned are inconsistent.

Comment: You could use call_once for this.

Comment: sorry edited the question the java thread call my main method.

Comment: This is what I am talking about. Use call_once in the c code - it will ensure the function will be called only once.